# Twilio Programmable Wireless Exception Handling

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

We have programmable wireless sims that we periodically collect usage information on.  There is currently 1 sim in our database with an invalid sid which causes the process to die (I will fix the sim data, but want to make sure that we are able to handle the thrown exception as well).  I have the call to the API wrapped in a try/catch, but it is not getting caught in the catch block regardless.  Any ideas whey this exception that is thrown is not caught in the catch?

```
async getDataUsageForDates(startIsoDate: string, endIsoDate: string): Promise<number> {
        const SID = this.sim.carrierId

        const isoStartDate = new Date(startIsoDate)
        const isoEndDate = new Date(endIsoDate)
        const start = new Date(Date.UTC(isoStartDate.getUTCFullYear(), isoStartDate.getUTCMonth(), isoStartDate.getUTCDate(), 0, 0, 0))
        const end = new Date(Date.UTC(isoEndDate.getUTCFullYear(), isoEndDate.getUTCMonth(), isoEndDate.getUTCDate(), 23, 59, 59))

        try {
            const usageResponse: UsageRecordInstance[] = await client.wireless.v1.sims(SID)
                                                                     .usageRecords.list({
                    start: start,
                    end: end
                })

            const usageRecord = usageResponse[0]  // twilio returns a collection but the totals are in the first record returned, so grab first record

            let dataTotal = 0

            if (usageRecord) {
                dataTotal = (usageRecord.data?.total === null) ? 0 : usageRecord.data?.total
            }

            return dataTotal
        } catch (err: any) {
            console.error(err)
            return 0
        }
```

Tried catching the exception and expected it to be caught

Comment: I'm thinking this maybe doesn't have anything to do with the twilio API at all, but rather it's because the call is async and hits catch execution before the exception is thrown?

Comment: I believe that I am experiencing this bug.  The exception is actually caught and the method does return the zero, however later in execution the exception is thrown again within the twilio Page module and I don't believe there is any way to catch the duplicate exception https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/issues/930

Answer (score 0):

Just in case any one else stumbles across this, there is a bug in the paging module in the twilio-node library and exceptions are thrown twice.  As far as I can tell there is no way to catch the second exception thrown and it doesn't sound like there is currently a timeline for fixing this in the twilio-node helper library.  A good workaround would be to just use axios to query and skip the helper library completely

```
const url = `https://wireless.twilio.com/v1/Sims/${SID}?Start=${start}&End=${end}`
const config = {
    method: 'get',
    url: url,
    auth: {
        username: TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID,
        password: TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN
    },
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
}

try {
    const usageResponse: UsageRecordInstance[] = await axios.request(config)

    // do something with response
} catch (err: any) {
    console.error(err)
}
```